# How to get jquery autocomplete values to search?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

The autocomplete part works, but clicking on the values in the drop down just puts them into the search box, and then I have to hit enter to perform the search. How do I get the values to search?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "SEO",
      "Responsive Design",
      "Google Local",
      "Twitter",
      "Social Media",
      "Web Design",
      "What is Google Authorship",
      "NFL",
      "Fantasy Football Rankings",
      "Kevin Sullivan",
      "Fantasy Football RB Rankings 2013",
      "Fantasy Football",
      "How to Buy Twitter Followers",
      "Advanced IFX",
      "Social Media Marketing",
      "NFL Schedule 2013-2014 Season",
      "Fantasy Football Breakdown",

    ];
    $(".search_box").autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  select: function(event, ui) { 
    $(".search_box").val(ui.item.value);
    $("#search").submit();
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$(".search_box").autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  select: function(event, ui) { 
    $(".search_box").val(ui.item.value);
    $("form").submit();
  }
})
```

Change "form" to select the specific form you're submitting for the search. This will fill in the search box with whatever value you clicked, then automatically submit the search form.

Here's a jsfiddle you can use to test: http://jsfiddle.net/4gArf/

Comment: That seemed to disable autocomplete. I only changed $("search").submit();

Comment: The CSS selector "search" will find all <search> tags. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Added a jsfiddle for your testing.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I really appreciate your help, but I'm still stuck. I updated my code sample. Maybe you can see something I'm missing?

Comment: Which browser do you use? If you can open up the developer tools or firebug and see what happens when you load the page or use the search field, it could give us some insight.

Comment: I'm using FF and have the debugger open. I can still search, but the autocomplete isn't responding.

Comment: Any chance you can send a link to the page so I can see it myself?

Comment: I created a more detailed post of what I'm trying to accomplish here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051229/how-to-jquery-ui-autocomplete-plug-in-to-search

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [`documentation`](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) the `source` property could point to a remote endpoint that will return the data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.search_box').autocomplete({
        source: '/remote.php'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out, but that is a little too advanced for my dumb ass. Is there a way to just search when you click on the autocomplete values?