# How to use the jQuery UI Autocomplete plug-in to search?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to create a site search similar to Google using the jQuery UI Autocomplete plug-in.

When somebody searches the autocomplete assists the search. That part is working (image) on my site: http://www.advancedifx.com/

The problem is, if you click on a drop down selection, in my image example I selected: Search Engine Optimization,  but all that a click does is put the text into the search box, and then you have to hit enter. I need help with getting the selection to perform a search.

Please note that my Javascript skills are beginner lever and it took me three days to get this far. If you think you can help please show me exactly where and what I need to modify.

Thanks in advance

[image]

```
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
  "SEO",
  "Responsive Design",
  "Google Local",
  "Twitter",
  "Social Media",
  "Web Design",

];
$( ".search_box" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the api: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

You have access to the `select` event.

```
$( ".search_box" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(ui); // you can see output of this in your dev console

    var searchTerm = ui.item; // pretty sure item will give you what you want

    // you can then trigger your button click or form submit (whatever you're doing)
    // passing along the searchTerm

   $('.top_bar_search').find('form').submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried using your advice, but No go or I'm doing something wrong. [link]'     <script>
   $(function() {

    var availableTags = [
      "SEO",
      "Responsive Design",
      "Google Local",
      "Twitter",
      "Social Media",
      "Web Design",
  ];

$( ".search_box" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(ui);

    var searchTerm = ui.item;
  }
});

  });
     
  </script>'

Comment: You need to trigger your form or search function.

Comment: I don't know how to do that?

Comment: Try my edit. Don't forget to remove the `console.log`, it will break IE.

Comment: That didn't work either. Oh well, I won't waste anymore of your time. I thank you kindly for your time and patience.

Comment: If you add this line: "$('.search_box').val(searchTerm); $('form.search').submit();" into your code after "var searchTerm = ui.item;" then I can visit your website and debug it for you.

Comment: I added the line you suggested. Again, thank you for assisting me. http://www.advancedifx.com/

Comment: You added the line in quotes, so it won't execute.

Comment: Nice it's executing, but I'm getting "Your search for "[object Object]" did not match any products." on all searches.